# Cross-origin request from AmpersandJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, ampersand.js

There is following AmpersandJS model

```
var AmpersandModel = require('ampersand-model');

module.exports = AmpersandModel.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://0.0.0.0:4567/api/v1/people',
    props: {
        id: 'any',
        name: ['string', true, ''],
        wins: ['number', true, 0],
        draws: ['number', true, 0],
        looses: ['number', true, 0]
    },

    ajaxConfig: function () {
        return {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "accept, authorization, origin"
            },
            xhrFields: {
                'withCredentials': false
            }
        };
    }
});
```

When 'save' is called on the model, request method converts to OPTIONS and an obvious error appears

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://0.0.0.0:4567/api/v1/people. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: It has nothing to do specifically with ampersand.js. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and other headers should be sent by the server you are trying to access. See http://enable-cors.org/server.html, for example

Comment: they are set correctly according to documentation..

Comment: Your server must handle a CORS preflight request. It clearly is not doing this. All of the "Access-Control-*" headers you are sending from the browser are unnecessary, and you should remove them. Your _server_ must send those headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe may be happening here is that the server isn't sending the right headers. The model shouldn't need to define any CORS-related headers as the browser will already be sending the appropriate request headers in most cases.

As you can see at [CORS Headers overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Headers), the headers that you have defined in your ajaxConfig are the ones that the server needs to send in the response in order to allow your cross-origin request.